# Converting a recurrence relationship into a summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can find the $i th$ term of a recurrence relationship $Y$ like this:

$$\begin{equation}
Y_i=\sigma_i+\beta_iY_{i-1}
\end{equation}$$ where $\sigma$ and $\beta$ are normally distributed random variables.
I'd like to convert this into summation over $i=1..n$ something like this:

$$\begin{equation}
Y=\sigma_i+\displaystyle \sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\beta_iY_{i-1}
\end{equation}$$

I know this summation is wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start without the $\Sigma$ in there:
$$Y_i=\sigma_i+\beta_i(\sigma_{i-1}+\beta_{i-1}(\sigma_{i-2}+...))=
\sigma_i+\beta_i\sigma_{i-1}+\beta_i\beta_{i-1}\sigma_{i-2}=
\sum_{j=0}^i \left(\prod_{k=j+1}^i \beta_k\sigma_j\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. It looks beautifully simple, though I'm a little confused by the indices j and k. These are dummy indices?

Comment: Yeah, they're meaningless. It's like $Y_i$ is a sum over the first $i+1$ $\sigma$s, which are indexed by $j$, and each $\sigma_j$ has a coefficient that's a product of some $\beta$s, which are indexed by $k$-but $k$ starts over for each $\sigma_j$. Try unwrapping the expression for $Y_1, Y_2$ to see better how it works.